# Safari extension full control over tabs

Tags: tabs, safari

I have made a chrome extension that I should convert to safari and firefox. That's fine, but I want to have full control over tabs. In my chrome extension I have full control over the tab even if user changes location (index) or drag the tab to a new window. With Safari's API, I'm not sure if I can achieve the same control. I could not find any events that can give me information about these events. I will probably be able to achieve the same control with various tricks, but would rather avoid it if possible. Hope there is someone who has had the same challenge and solved it in an elegant way. thank you in advance.

Comment: I found a solution. I can make an id property on the tabs I open and search through all the tabs in all windows. That way, I find the tab even if a user has moved it to a different index or window.

Comment: The solution can be found here: https://github.com/kritollm/chrome-extension-api-for-safari-and-firefox/tree/master/chromeAPISafari